PHP - if a recursive function is called twice within itself in what order will the calls be made?
I have a program in Python that I'm trying to convert into PHP (as allowed by the program's licence) that draws random polygons. Part of this code contains a recursive function that splits the first polygon sent to it into two new polygons (polygon B and polygon A) then these polygons get split again by way of the recursive function, up to a pre-determined number of iterations (using the value in $depth, which is tested for inside the function but omitted from my code):
<?php

function generate_polygons($polygon, $depth, $polygon_type=NULL)
{
    // code omitted for clarity

    $this->generate_polygons($polygon_b, $depth-1, 'B');
    $this->generate_polygons($polygon_a, $depth-1, 'A');
}

$generate_polygons($starting_polygon, $depth);

?>

What I want to understand is how to visualize two levels of recursion to determine at what stage each polygon is split?

Have you tried adding some simple logging / echoing to the code so you can see what path it takes?

But in general code is executed sequentially, so if $this->generate_polygons($polygon_b, $depth-1, 'B'); causes more function calls within it, those would be executed first before it finally returns from all of those back to the parent function, and then runs the $this->generate_polygons($polygon_a, $depth-1, 'A'); line.

Thanks for your suggestions. I have tried logging it but the values make no sense to me and (generally) recursion makes my head hurt. The depth is set to 3 and the order (with depth value in brackets) is: STARTING POLYGON(3), B(2), B(1), B(0), A(0), A(1), B(0), A(0), A(2), B(1), B(0), A(0), A(1), B(0), A(0).

I'm having trouble telling the difference between the two methods you describe. What's the difference between "finish processing that" and "keep splitting the initial polygon B"?

Apologies for not explaining it properly. I am trying to work out exactly how the recursions are sequenced because I am comparing the output from my script with the Python code and about halfway through my script the polygons do not match up any more, so something is going wrong. What I meant before was: when the first polygon is split into two (B and A), will the recursion keep splitting the "B" side of the polygons until it hits the recursion limit, then it has to go back and split all of the "A" sides? I tried to draw up a dependency graph but I still don't really understand the sequence.

As ADyson says, PHP doesn't do anything special because the function call is recursive, it just runs things in the order you tell it to. Try drawing out a tree, where every node has a B and an A under it: the starting state has two branches, B(2) and A(2); B(2) has branches B(1) and A(1), and A(2) has its own B(1) and A(1); under each of those are the B(0) and A(0) leaves (four of each in total). Trace a route through the tree, always visiting B first, and only going back to A when everything under B is done. You'll find it matches the debug output you got.

@IMSoP Thank you very much. Once I can visualise this properly it will no doubt make more sense. I'll try and put a diagram together as suggested and then compare with the output.

With input from @ADyson and @IMSoP I have been able to produce a simple animation showing the exact sequencing of the recursion:

As already mentioned, PHP does not do anything different to other programming languages in this respect (each recursion is completed fully before moving on to the next recursion) but, for me, the actual sequencing is a lot easier to understand now that I can fully visualize the process.
Thank you again for everyone's help.
